# Stash only pulled changes using git?

Tags: git

How can I specifically stash the pulled changes?

Here is the Use-case For-example

- Some changes available on local but not commit
- I have pulled the updated code For-example there is an issue occurs after that
- Now I want to stash the pulled changes & don't want to stash my local changes

How can I do that?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please clarify it or add an example.

Comment: If you had `fetch`ed remote changes instead of `pull`ing them in the first place, life would be easier

Comment: Did a merge conflict occur when pulling the changes? If it didn't, the pull is already commited and cannot be stashed. However you could checkout the version before the pull using `git checkout HEAD^` to test if the issue already occured in that version (assuming that you didn't commit anything after pulling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least some of this should be a comment (not an answer) but it won't fit.  I'll answer what you didn't ask instead. :-)

I *think* your answer is to just:

```
git checkout -b newbranch HEAD@{1}
git commit        # optional, but a good idea
```

Read on to see what this does, why I think it will work for you, and what you should do in the future to avoid having to recover from this.

#### The problem with the question as asked

The question makes no sense because `git pull` does not *pull changes*, it fetches and then (usually<sup>1</sup>) merges *commits*.  Commits are not changes; commits not only represent, but in fact *are*, whole work-trees.  This might seem like a distinction without a difference, and in fact, changesets and work-trees are somewhat inter-convertible, but it does matter, especially in Git (less so in other version control systems that are better at hiding implementation details).

Meanwhile, what `git stash` does is make commits.  You cannot *make* commits from stuff you've pulled, because the commits you fetched in pull's first step *are already* commits.  (Incidentally, the commits that `git stash` makes are mostly pretty ordinary.  What's special about them is that they are deliberately *not on any branch*.  Well, that, and the index commit has the *form* of a merge commit, but is not a normal merge in any sense.  Its "merginess" is used instead to let the stash code find the work-tree and optional untracked-files commits easily.)

---

<sup>1</sup>I say "usually" in part because you can set it up to do `rebase` instead, and in part because of the "pre-merge checks" noted below.

---

#### What you did so far

Your use-case example is helpful though, as it's only the third bullet-point that makes no sense, at least using Git's definitions of words.

> - Some changes available on local but not commit
> - I have pulled the updated code For-example there is an issue occurs after that
> - Now I want to stash the pulled changes & don't want to stash my local changes

So it sounds like you had a dirty (changed, maybe even `git add`-ed, but definitely not `git commit`-ed) work-tree when you ran `git pull`.

Now, the key to all of this is that `git pull` *means* `git fetch && git merge`, more or less, and in Git, there are three big things to be concerned about at any given time:

- your commits: the one you're currently using (the "HEAD" or `HEAD`), plus all the others inside your repository;
- your index (or "staging area"); and
- your work-tree.

When you run `git fetch`, this simply adds *new* commits to your repository.  It has no effect on any existing commit.  It *cannot* change any existing commit; that's physically impossible; and in fact, *all* Git's internal objects are constant, once they are written.

Because of this, the `git fetch` step is entirely safe.

The `git merge` step, however, is *not*.

What `git merge` does is complex and messy to describe in detail.  The *summary* is simple enough, but in practice, it uses both your index and work-tree to do all the work.  This is where we get into trouble if the index and/or work-tree are not "clean" at the start of the `git merge` step.

For much more about this, see other questions (and/or tutorials) on `git merge`.  For what to do *now*, see the description of `git merge --abort` in [the `git merge` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html):

> `--abort`
>
> Abort the current conflict resolution process, and try to reconstruct the pre-merge state.
>
> If there were uncommitted worktree changes present when the merge started, *git merge --abort* will **in some cases be unable to reconstruct these changes.** It is therefore recommended to **always commit or stash your changes before running git merge**.
>
> *git merge --abort* is equivalent to *git reset --merge* when `MERGE_HEAD` is present.

(The boldface here is mine, and it calls out what you should do in the future.)  Fortunately, the documentation [goes on to make this claim](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_pre_merge_checks):

> #### PRE-MERGE CHECKS
>
> Before applying outside changes, you should get your own work in good shape and committed locally, so it will not be clobbered if there are conflicts. See also [git-stash(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-stash.html). ***git pull* and *git merge* will stop without doing anything when local uncommitted changes overlap with files that *git pull/git merge* may need to update.**
>
> To avoid recording unrelated changes in the merge commit, *git pull* and *git merge* will also abort if there are any changes registered in the index relative to the `HEAD` commit. (One exception is when the changed index entries are in the state that would result from the merge already.)
>
> If all named commits are already ancestors of `HEAD`, *git merge* will exit early with the message "Already up-to-date."

If the boldfaced claim (boldfacing mine again) is correct (it seems to be today but I got burned by `git pull` in the ancient past, Git 1.5 era, and still mostly avoid it these days), *and* you had no merge conflicts and got a merge, then your changes are still uncommitted.  I made a sample repository with an upstream, made a change locally to `README` that I did not commit, and then used `git pull` to bring in the unrelated changes.  When it finished:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'mt2/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   README

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Let's also assume that we don't have the case where `git merge` started, but then complained about conflicts.  If you *do* have that case, you can try using `git merge --abort` to stop the in-progress merge.  Whatever you are left with is the best Git can do automatically.

So, let's move on to where the merge has succeeded, but the resulting code does not work.

#### Error recovery

What I think you are asking to do, in this SO posting, is to get back to the state you had before you ran `git pull`, after the `git merge` step succeeded.  That is, you want:

- your `HEAD` commit restored to where it was before;
- your index restored to its previous state; and
- your work-tree restored to *its* previous state.

The example merge I just made with my `git pull` was a so-called *fast forward*, not a real merge, so `HEAD^` is *not* necessarily the commit that was `HEAD` before.  Fortunately, Git keeps the previous value of `HEAD` in the reflog for `HEAD`.  Don't worry if not *all* of this makes sense to you right away—the point is that `git fetch` brought in some commit(s), and `git merge` then succeeded, which did something to `HEAD` to change it.

The *previous* value of `HEAD`, before the last time something (in this case, merge) changed `HEAD`, is always<sup>2</sup> available as `HEAD@{1}`.  The value from one step before that is `HEAD@{2}`, and so on.  (Note that as soon as you make *another* change to your `HEAD`, everything gets bumped up one: what was `HEAD@{2}` becomes `HEAD@{3}`, what was `HEAD@{1}` becomes `HEAD@{2}`, and what was `HEAD` becomes `HEAD@{1}`.  This is going to happen again in a moment when we run a `git checkout` that also changes `HEAD`.)  To see *all* your changes to `HEAD` over time, run `git reflog`.  Git also records changes to each branch name, so you can run `git reflog master`.

---

<sup>2</sup>Well, "always" with two caveats:

1. Reflog entries expire.  By default, some last 30 days and some last 90 days.  Git keeps the ones it deems "more useful" for the longer time.  Until you need to care, just think of this as "you get about a month before it gets dicey."  You can configure this to be longer or shorter, too.
2. You can enable or disable reflogs.  By default, they are enabled for *your* repositories, but not for bare repositories on servers.

---

The reflog gives us an easy way to get the previous value of `HEAD`, but what about the index and/or work-tree?  Well, note that my `git merge` left my *uncommitted* changes uncommitted.  It also says in the documentation that `git merge` will error out (without even starting) if I have new files in my index—i.e., if I have `git add`ed some updated files.  But, if I had `git add`ed some of my uncommitted files, and the files I had `add`-ed matched the upstream's commit, *those* files would now be committed.  The *contents* of those files are thus safe, but it could be quite hard to remember which files were modified with respect to my previous `HEAD`.  (That's another reason to try to avoid this error-recovery process by committing, or at least stashing, in the first place.)

So, if we abandon the idea of restoring the index and work-tree perfectly every time, we can consider instead a subset of cases: those where there are no new files in the index (we ran no `git add`s), and all the changes to work-tree files are still uncommitted after a successful pull-driven merge.  For this to be true, the *difference* between the current HEAD (`HEAD`) and the previous (`HEAD@{1}`) must, necessarily, be in *other* files.

To put this as plainly as I can:

- Comparing `HEAD` vs `HEAD@{1}`, there may be some changed files.  (Use `git diff --name-status HEAD@{1} HEAD` to see them, for instance.)
- There are also files that, in `git status` output, are shown as `changes not staged for commit`.  (Use `git status` to see them.)
- **But** every file in the second list is *not* in the first!

It's this last "but" that is the key.  When we do:

`git checkout name-or-commit-ID`

to move `HEAD` to another commit—either "detaching" it, or moving to another branch—Git will work hard to check out, into the index and work-tree, *only* those files that differ between "where we are now" and "where we need to be" to complete the checkout.  Any *other* files, currently modified in the work-tree, remain untouched.  (There are some thorny edge cases with files that only exist in one of the two commits, or where your index has some staged changes, but we'll just ignore them.)

So, if you:

```
git checkout HEAD@{1}
```

(assuming it works) you will get your `HEAD` set to its previous value, and your work-tree will be updated to the files recorded in that commit, except for currently-modified work-tree files which will simply be carried over.  You will then be in "detached HEAD" mode, so now it's time to create a new branch name pointing to the current commit:

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

You can combine these into one command, `git checkout -b newbranch HEAD@{1}`, which is what I suggested way back at the top.

#### This is all error-recovery

The main mistake here is doing `git pull` (or `git merge`) with changes that are not yet committed.  Because `git merge` needs to munch on the index and work-tree, and their states are *not* recorded somewhere permanently, this can get you in trouble, getting you into a new state that is not easy to transform back.

If you make a commit first, or run `git stash` which simply makes two (or even three) commits, you have actual Git objects recording the state.  At that point, it's easy—or at least eas**ier**—to get back to the previous state, as it's saved away in a permanent place.

Interestingly, `git rebase` forbids running rebase with uncommitted changes, making you use `git stash` or `git commit` first.  If you configure `git pull` to run `git rebase` instead of running `git merge`, you will not have to do this kind of error recovery.  If `git merge` did the same thing, none of this would come up in the first place.  (Of course, people find that annoying, enough so that rebase now has an "autostash" option.  Of course merge could also have an autostash option.)

Answer (score 0):

To stash your local changes use:

```
git stash
```

To list stashes use:

```
git stash list
```

To see a stash use:

```
git stash show <stash-id>
```

To re-deploy the last stash (get the changes back) use:

```
git stash pop
```

To remove (throw away) the last stash use:

```
git stash drop
```

That said, it's not clear what you want to do. You can only stash your **local uncommitted** changes.

When you say *pulled changes* you maybe want to go back to a previous commit.
You can do this with:

```
git checkout <commit-id>
```

To know the `<commit-id>` use:

```
git log
```

You only need to input the first part of the code (as long as it is unique), such as:

```
git checkout 9fae3
```